# Identify this 2-pin component - markings include AUPO A4-F

Tags: identification, components

This part went bad, I have no idea what it is to order it on Mueller site, can you identify it for me?

Thanks to anyone that does.

.

[image: Photo of the component]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an AUPO A4-F 130°C 2A thermal fuse.

Datasheet available [here](https://www.tme.eu/Document/b92b7bb6ed5feb4ae4e7e2b64d32b340/A-F.pdf).

Here is a copy of a relevant part of the datasheet:

[image: Part of Aupo datasheet showing parameters for A4-F fuse]

Comment: Thanks, if i bypass it the circuit should work?

Comment: Depends why it blew. If there's a short, you'll probably make things worse running it without a fuse.

Comment: @Moab - Hi, "*if i bypass it the circuit should work?*" That depends why the fuse blew in the first place. If you *know* what happened to cause the fuse to open originally, *and* you have fixed the underlying cause, *and* if you accept the lack of safety which is inherent  in the removal of a safety device like that, then *perhaps* the circuit (whatever that is) *might* work. Clearly, since I don't know all the details and don't have your (mains-powered?) device here to test, I'm not going to recommend you to do that. Your choice, your risk, your responsibility. It could explode or catch fire!

Comment: Its a simple 120v AC small fan motor.

Comment: Attempting to solder a replacement thermal fuse can easily result in melting it. You should look to crimp the replacement into the circuit.